# visual paradigm sequence diagram: Creating Life Lines with different lengths

Tags: sequence-diagram, visual-paradigm

When I create an new life line in visual paradigm it alwas starts on the top of my diagram.

Now I want to draw a sequence diagram where some classes get create while the process is running. So they can't start at the beginning, because they don't exist back then.

Is there a possiblity to add a new life line lower than the old one?

Answer (score 3):

Sure, in [Visual Paradigm](https://www.visual-paradigm.com) you can simply use the Create Message to indicate the creation of new instance (lifeline). This can be done by create new lifeline from scratch by drag out the [Resource Catalog](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/support/documents/vpuserguide/1283/27/6253_resourcecent.html) icon and drop it to the blank space of your diagram, and then select **Create Message -> Lifeline** from popup.

[image: The creation of the instance is triggered by the message]

Or if you already have the target lifeline created you can drag out the Resource Catalog icon and drop it over the target lifeline, and then select **Create Message** from popup.

[image: Connect to existing lifeline with Create Message]

And here is the result.

[image]